# How to connect ejabberd with mysql on ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, xmpp, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd on my localhost (WAMP) and its working properly for Mnesia database(default), Now I want to connect it with mysql but unable to do .
I have tried with many link, example,
Firstly created a database ejabberd with ejabberd schema and then
 1. Commented the line,

```
From {auth_method, internal}.
To %%{auth_method, internal}.
```

after then,

```
FROM %%{auth_method, odbc}.
To 
{auth_method, odbc}.
```

then,

```
%%
%% MySQL server:
%%
{odbc_server, {mysql, "localhost", "ejabberd", "root", "MyPassword"}}.
```

and finally added **_odbc** in some modules

```
{mod_last_odbc,     []},
{mod_offline_odbc,  []},
{mod_privacy_odbc,  []},
{mod_private_odbc,  []},
{mod_pubsub_odbc,   [ % requires mod_caps ...
{mod_roster_odbc,   []},
{mod_vcard_odbc,    []},
```

But after these steps unable to start ejabberd server, i tried many times but all time i need to reinstall the ejabberd, even rollback of processes does not worked.
Your help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*step 1) Create database ejabberd*

---

*step 2)Import [this](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/sql/mysql.sql) schema to ejabberd database*

---

*step 3)open your configuration file(ejabberd.cfg) and make following changes*

From {auth_method, internal}.
To %%{auth_method, internal}.
after then,

```
FROM %%{auth_method, odbc}.
To 
{auth_method, odbc}.
then,

%%
%% MySQL server:
%%
{odbc_server, {mysql, "localhost", "ejabberd", "root", "MyPassword"}}.
```

Change mod_last to mod_last_odbc

Change mod_offline to mod_offline_odbc

Change mod_roster to mod_roster_odbc

Change mod_private to mod_private_odbc

Change mod_privacy to mod_privacy_odbc

Change mod_pubsub to mod_pubsub_odbc

Change mod_vcard to mod_vcard_odbc

---

*step 4)This is where most people fumble.Install Erlang-Mysql drivers : http://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mysql/trunk/*

You can copy them to the same directory were all the other ejabberd beam files are already copied: /usr/lib/ejabberd/ebin/

---

*step 5)Restart ejabberd.*

Thats it.

Source :

https://www.ejabberd.im/Using%20ejabberd%20with%20MySQL%20native%20driver

https://www.ejabberd.im/node/4125

http://srijan.me/ejabberd-storing-data-in-mysql/

Comment: After installed, I access the server, here is what I see. http://imgur.com/j4RcxWr Is that ok, any advice? @jayesh-jain

Comment: ejabberd web console does not show user if the database used is not the internal Mnesia database.

Comment: Is the link for step 4 still relevant? Can we use [this](https://github.com/processone/p1_mysql) instead?

Comment: @JeelShah as step 4 link is dead now  , how did you configure ejabberd with mysql ?

Comment: @rigal Did you figure out how to solve your problem? Sorry for the late reply. Setup a private chat with me - I don't mind guiding you. The process can be lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

I following this guide, and I am able to start server fine. When I am using 
$sudo ejabberdctl register user_1 localhost user_1
I got "User user_1@localhost successfully registered"

however, when I go to the database, "select * from users", I dont see any records, I also query all the tables, no see any data, all empty. Although I can login via the user_1/user_1 in XMPP client like Pidgin, any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your log statements to see what exactly is failing? I think you probably need to rebuild ejabberd with the --enable-odbc option.

Comment: Hi Chrisyunker, Sorry for late response, unable to generate log file,can you help me ?

Comment: Set loglevel to 5 (debug) in ejabberd.cfg: {loglevel, 5}. Restart ejabberd. Post contents of ./var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log to a gist and share link.

Comment: =ERROR REPORT==== 2014-01-10 18:20:09 ===
C(<0.37.0>:ejabberd_check:63) : ejabberd is configured to use 'mysql', but the following Erlang modules are not installed: '[mysql,
                                                                                                                             mysql_auth,
                                                                                                                             mysql_conn,
                                                                                                                             mysql_recv]'

Comment: So it looks like you're configured to use mysql, but don't have the libraries installed. You need to get these from another source. Check this link: https://github.com/processone/mysql (I see they added a p1_ prefix, so you will have to update ejabberd source code which references it accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give a updated answer, may be useful for later search.

In ejabberd.yml add to the end of the file

```
############## DATABASE CONFIGS ###########################
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "ejabberd"
sql_password: "sqldatabasepassword"
sql_port: 3306
auth_method: sql
```

And to tell Ejabberd consider SQL database, add at the begining of the file after host or after log_rotate_count

```
default_db: sql
```

There you go you have connected your sql database to ejabberd. Make sure your database have schema required by ejabberd.